# How to estimate load for a live server and tailor it to a less powerful QA server?

Tags: automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I understand that a test environment should match the live environment as much as possible. Unfortunately in my case (the project is a Web CMS) a QA server with the same specifications as the live one cannot be supplied.

Does it make sense to define the load metrics and reduce them to a proportion to account for a server with reduced specifications?  Would the margin of error of the results be reasonable?

Otherwise what is a sensible approach and can you point me to specific literature that might address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot step into the same river twice. Even if your live server and test server are perfectly identical in configuration, usage, data etc. you might have differences in the results.

If in your case the test environment is weaker than the live one, then you can benefit from the situation: you might detect scalability problems on the test environment before it occurs on the live version. However, to maximize the chance for this, you need to implement some stress tests, simulating the case when many users are using costly features at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Running a load test against scaled down environment won't make any harm, but it may be very helpful as well, among things you can test are:

- Checking for memory leaks. If you conduct a long-running test and there are issues with your application like not closed file handles, not freed up memory when the object is not required any more, etc. it will be easier to detect it using deployment on the low-spec server
- Checking components integration and configuration like web/application server settings, database server settings, database connectivity parameters, etc.
- If your application scales, you can test this functionality as well and also determine the scaling factor and project this to live system
- You can run your test under a [Profiler Tool telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to detect performance-related bugs which will occur in the production

So if you cannot use live server even in the dead time (i.e. nights or weekends) you can still add some value by running tests on lower spec server. See [Performance Testing in a Scaled Down Environment. Part Two: 5 Things You Can Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environment-part-two-5-things-you-can-test) article for more detailed explanation on some of the above points and extra information.